# Loop in a loop and If statement?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement

I am a beginner programming, I want to ask multiple questions using arrays and tell the user whether he got each question right or wrong, which I managed to get it running, but now how do I implement the code so that the user will only have up to 3 attempts to get a question right.

```
for(int n = 0; n <QArray.length; n++)
{
    System.out.println("Question" + (n+1));
    System.out.println(QArray[n]);

    String ans = scanner.nextLine();

    if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase(AArray[n]))
    {
        System.out.println("That is correct!");
    }
    else   
    {     
        System.out.println("That is incorrect!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use a `for` loop which counts up to 3.

Comment: `while (attempts > 0)` and then decrement `attempts` each time?

Answer (score 0):

So if I correctly understand your goal, you've a list of questions, and whilst they have made fewer than three failed attempts at them, you would like for the users to get to try and answer them?

Using your existing style, you could do something like

```
for(int n = 0; n < QArray.length; n++)
{
    System.out.println("Question" + (n+1));
    System.out.println(QArray[n]);

    int incorrectAnswers = 0;
    while(incorrectAnswers < 3)
    {
        String ans = scanner.nextLine();
        if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase(AArray[n]))
        {
            System.out.println("That is correct!");
            break;
        }
        else   
        {     
            System.out.println("That is incorrect!");
            incorrectAnswers++;
        }
    }
}
```

Depending how the data is displayed and transferred and concerns regarding security etc, it would make for easier to manage code to have a QuestionAnswer object that contains the question and the answer, as well as a method for what constitutes a valid answer (e.g. case insensitive, or maybe you want to accept multiple words etc, whatever works for your case), so you could end up with code that looks like the below.

```
for(int i = 0; i < questionAnswerArray.length; i++)
{
    QuestionAnswer qa = questionAnswerArray[i];

    System.out.println("Question " + (i+1));
    System.out.println(qa.getQuestion());

    int incorrectAnswers = 0;
    while(incorrectAnswers < 3)
    {
        String ans = scanner.nextLine();
        if (qa.isValidAnswer(ans))
        {
            System.out.println("That is correct!");
            break;
        }
        else   
        {     
            System.out.println("That is incorrect!");
            incorrectAnswers++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `while` with the number of attempt you need:

```
for (int n = 0; n < QArray.length; n++) {
    System.out.println("Question" + (n + 1));
    System.out.println(QArray[n]);
    int attempt = 3;

    while (attempt > 0) {
        System.out.print("Please enter the answer: ");
        String ans = scanner.nextLine();
        if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase(AArray[n])) {
            System.out.println("That is correct!");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("That is incorrect!");
        }
        attempt--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Put a second loop inside the first.

```
for(int n = 0; n < QArray.length; n++) {
  boolean correct = false;
  for(int m = 0; m < 3; m ++) {
    String ans = scanner.nextLine();
    if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase(AArray[n])) {
      System.out.println("That is correct!");
      correct = true;
      break;
    } else {     
      System.out.println("That is incorrect!");
    }
  }
  if(!correct) {
    //something
  } else {
    //something else
  }
}
```

Note the `break;`.  That command will exit the inner for-loop (which contains the scanner input) when a correct answer is submitted.  If the user doesn't get the right answer in 3 tries, the for-loop will end by reaching the end of its counter.